# Is every unitary representation of the Poincare group a direct sum of Wigner's irreducible representations?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, group-theory, representation-theory, poincare-symmetry

Is Wigner's classification of unitary irreducible representations of the Poincare  group [1] sufficient for constructing all unitary representations of the Poincare group by taking direct sums?

The naive answer is, yes, because we might naively apply the general theorem about representations that "every ***finite-dimensional*** unitary representation on a Hilbert space is the direct sum of irreducible representations"[2]. However this theorem is only true for finite dimensional representations whereas for unitary irreps of Poincare we have infinite dimensional representations, and thus this may leave room for representations which cannot be constructed via direct sums of irreducible representations. Is this possible? If so, have such representations been studied?

[1] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wigner%27s_classification

[2] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irreducible_representation#Reducible_and_irreducible_representations